# How to speed up this code with Cython?

Tags: python, performance, cython

```
def check(barcode):
    if not len(barcode) == 13:
        return False

    digits = list(map(int, barcode))

    # 1. Add the values of the digits in the 
    # even-numbered positions: 2, 4, 6, etc.
    even_sum = digits[1] + digits[3] + digits[5] + digits[7] + digits[9] + digits[11]

    # 2. Multiply this result by 3.
    even_sum_three = even_sum * 3

    # 3. Add the values of the digits in the 
    # odd-numbered positions: 1, 3, 5, etc.
    odd_sum = digits[0] + digits[2] + digits[4] + digits[6] + digits[8] + digits[10]

    # 4. Sum the results of steps 2 and 3.
    total_sum = even_sum_three + odd_sum

    # 5. The check character is the smallest number which,
    # when added to the result in step 4, produces a multiple of 10.
    next_ten = (math.ceil(total_sum / 10)) * 10
    check_digit = next_ten - total_sum

    # 6. if the check digit and the last digit of the 
    # barcode are OK return true;
    if check_digit == digits[12]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I have the above code. It calculates the checksum of an ean number. I tried to speed it by using Cython. This code gets used in a loop. The variable barcode is a string.

But I failed to improve the speed. I tried:

- `np.array(list(map(int, barcode)))` - That made it slightly slower
- `np.ceil()` instead of `math.ceil()` - Also made it slightly slower
- `cdef bool def check(....` - Also did not help

What else could I do?

Comment: What's the initial format `barcode` is in?

Comment: @orlp: A 13-character UPC.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I mean in Python, there is no object type called `UPC` :) Is it a string, or?

Comment: @orlp: [UPCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code) are sequences of 13 numerals, consisting of 12 identifying numerals and a check numeral.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm asking whether the input type is expected to be a string, a tuple of characters, etc - during runtime. I'm not wondering what an UPC is.

Comment: barcode is a string.

Comment: I usually get better results when I try to optimize the loop as a whole, rather than optimizing a function which is called by the loop many times.  If you provide the source for the loop as well, I think we can be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by optimizing your function itself. Having a look at

```
    # 5. The check character is the smallest number which,
    # when added to the result in step 4, produces a multiple of 10.
    next_ten = (math.ceil(total_sum / 10)) * 10
    check_digit = next_ten - total_sum
```

you could also do something like `next_ten = 10 - total_sum % 10` to get the check character. There you got rid of the `math.ceil`. As extra, this code also works in Python 2. So at the end, collapsing all your code, you could end up with just doing

```
def check(barcode):
    if not len(barcode) == 13:
        return False
    return not (3*sum(map(int,barcode[1::2]))+sum(map(int,barcode[::2])))%10
```

Of course you could also use list comprehension or `itertools`, but in my testing there was not much difference to account for. But the "most" efficient way to do it, was not to use any fancy python programming technique at all:

```
def check(bc):
    if not len(bc) == 13:
        return False
    return not (3*(int(bc[1])+int(bc[3])+int(bc[5])+int(bc[7])+int(bc[9])+int(bc[11]))+int(bc[0])+int(bc[2])+int(bc[4])+int(bc[6])+int(bc[8])+int(bc[10])+int(bc[12]))%10
```

A note at the end: With all my tests, Python 2 was faster.